# How do I use jack henry in my application and get started with the api?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I checked the docs on Jack Henry's website and it didn't show any information on how to use it on your website for banking. How do I get started using it in my website so that users can have an online banking experience. Can someone provide me some links that tell how to use Jack Henry on my website?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're talking about the Digital Toolkit, that requires access to the [Banno digital banking platform](https://banno.com/).

Ordinarily, financial institutions (e.g., banks and credit unions, the typical clients of Jack Henry) are the ones who use Banno to offer digital banking to their customers and members. If you're working directly with a bank or a credit union that has Banno, their Banno administrator should be able to help you with access to API credentials.

Notably, we also offer developers access to the Digital Toolkit via our demo institution (which is named [Garden](https://www.garden-fi.com/)). Please review our [Accessing the Digital Toolkit](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/accessing-the-digital-toolkit/) guide. That guide covers these topics related to the Digital Toolkit and our demo institution:

- Signing up for a developer account
- Creating a test user
- Generating an External Application
- Configuring a plugin

By the way, we also highly recommend registering for the monthly Toolkit Meetup where we answer technical Q&A from the audience: https://www.jackhenry.com/resources/events